# Как можно реализовать выполнение большого количества задач за малое время на PHP?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Есть в интернетах сервисы, которые позволяют публиковать отложенные посты сразу в несколько соцсетей, в т.ч. и во ВКонтакте. У них есть много пользователей и постов, которые нужно постить в одну и ту же минуту.

У меня есть приложение на PHP, которое будет делать примерно то же самое (по крайней мере, оно должно успевать делать очень много запросов в одну минуту). Если выполнять всё последовательно, для каждого пользователя, то это будет выполняться далеко не минуту (учитывая паузы, чтобы не привысить лимит запросов в секунду) и, значит, это не вариант.

После мне пришла идея найти что-то, что будет имитировать многопоточность на php. Нашёл, например, библиотеку [PHPThreads](https://github.com/wielski/PHPThreads), попробовал её с небольшим количеством пользователей и их групп, в которые нужно постить записи. Вроде, несмотря на то, что количество групп, в которые нужно запостить по несколько постов, варьировалось от 1 до 3, скрипт всегда укладывался в 40 секунд, что приемлемо. Однако, что будет потом, когда этих групп и постов станет больше? Не увеличиться ли время выполнения?

Подскажите, с помощью чего вы реализовали бы что-то подобное? Может вы сталкивались с такой задачей и можете натолкнуть меня на более правильный путь?

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, тут нужна не многопоточность, а асинхронность.
Как вариант, можно отправлять приложению запрос на добавление записи в соцсети. Но приложение не побежит публиковать пост, а лишь зарегистрирует заявку на публикацию и ответит утвердительно (что заявка успешно зарегистрирована) или отрицательно (какие-то проблемы с регистраией заявки). После этого, например по таймеру, будет пытаться асинхронно(!) исполнять зарегистрированные заявки. Т.е. в момент исполнения заявок приложение должно уметь параллельно регистрировать новые заявки.

Стоит взглянуть на связку [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) и [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/)

Comment: Об ReactPHP я не знал, но буду смотреть. Спасибо большое.